# Bamboo's 3.1.1 manual dependency management / dependency blocking feature not working as expected?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, build-dependencies

We're using Bamboo as our CI environment and have several build dependencies in place (using manual dependency management & the dependency blocking feature). We're using SVN polling as our build strategy with all projects having the same polling frequency.

Assume we have the following build plan structure:

- a parent build plan PA for project A,
- a child build plan CB for project B being dependent on PA, having selected 'Block build if parent Plans have unbuilt changes' as the dependency blocking strategy

Our goal is to setup a dependency tree so that:

- if project B should get built, first check if A has changes and if so, build PA first and block CB, resume CB as soon as PA has finished
- do this for manual as well as automatic builds (builds triggered as a result of the SVN polling)

The described goal above seems to be exactly what the dependency blocking feature (see http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Setting+up+Build+Dependencies) is all about. However, I either have a configuration error or don't correctly understand this feature.

To test, I've constructed the following case:

- create a class DummyClassA in A
- create a class DummyClassB in B which references DummyClassA so that project A has first to be built for project B to compile
  *manually invoke CB

I would have expected that through the configuration mentioned above, CB realizes that the parent project has changes and thus needs to block CB, build PA and resume CB.
However, what happened was that CB was attempted to be built and obviously failed (compile error) as DummyClassA was not yet known to project B. It seems as if there is *no active checking* of the SVN for the parent project A when CB is manually triggered, is that correct?

What am I missing here? I'm pretty sure that there must be a simple solution as this scenario comes up in virtually every serious software project so I expect Bamboo to handle this out of the box correctly.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Best,
Chris